# GNU make on Windows - unable to execute a simple command

Tags: windows, emacs, makefile

The following makefile fails on executing a simple command with an error in emacs compile. It is verified to work from command prompt. What can be the issue with it ?

```
SHELL = cmd.exe

test:
      rd /s /q output

make test --debug
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `test' does not exist.
Must remake target `test'.
rd /s /q output
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: The command rm /s /q output is on the next line starting with a tab. So the syntax is OK as far as make is concerned.

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the makefile you show in the example and the output you get don't match, so your question is not correct.  Your makefile says `rm ...` but your output says `rd ...`.  Please edit your question to fix the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was just trying to provide a test version of the original file to show the issue.

Comment: The issue is with COMSPEC set to c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe in init.el for Emacs shell to work on windows. This is somehow causing this weird issue possibly due to slashes. Modified it to just cmd.exe to make it work.